# How can I run the Perl debugger at runtime with PERLDB_OPTS?

Tags: perl, debugging

I have following Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
sub bar { foo() }
sub foo { }
sub hello { bar(); }
hello();
```

Which produces following output

```
$ PERLDB_OPTS="NonStop frame=1" perl -d 1.pl > /dev/null
Package 1.pl.
  entering DB::Obj::_init
  entering main::hello
   entering main::bar
    entering main::foo
```

I need to enable the debugger only before the `bar()` function call. How can I do that?

What I've tried:

1. [Enbugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Enbugger/lib/Enbugger.pod) + `DB::parse_options`

   ```
   $ cat 1.pl
   #!/usr/bin/env perl
   sub bar { foo() }
   sub foo { }
   sub hello {
       require Enbugger;
       Enbugger->load_debugger();
       DB::parse_options("NonStop frame=1");
       bar();
       Enbugger->stop;
   }
   hello();
   $ perl 1.pl > /dev/null
     entering CODE(0x1c551d0)
      entering CODE(0x1d23018)
       entering strict::import
      entering CODE(0x1d23ac8)
    Package /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/Errno.pm.
      entering Errno::TIEHASH
     entering CODE(0x1c551b8)
      entering CODE(0x1d72b40)
   entering strict::import
    Package /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/Tie/Hash/NamedCapture.pm.
      entering XSLoader::load
                NonStop = '1'
                  frame = '1'
     entering CODE(0x1bdeca8)
      entering warnings::unimport
   ```

It seems like is working bebecause if I change to `frame=2` there will be more output. But the output is wrong, and the expected is:

```
Package 1.pl.
    entering DB::Obj::_init
       entering main::bar
        entering main::foo
```

2. [DB global variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/DB.html#Global-Variables):

   ```
    $ cat 1.pl
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    sub bar { foo() }
    sub foo { }
    sub hello {
        require "perl5db.pl";
        $DB::signal = 1;
        bar();
        $DB::single = 1;
    }
    hello();
    $ PERLDB_OPTS="NonStop frame=1" perl 1.pl > /dev/null
   ```

No output :(

Answer (score 1):

For now, I used the following hack - run the script with `-d NonStop frame=0` and set `$DB::frame=1` at a place from which I want to get a stack trace.

```
$ cat 1.pl
```

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
sub bar { foo() }

sub foo { }

sub hello {
    $DB::frame = 1;
    bar();
    $DB::frame = 0;
}

hello();
```

```
$ PERL5OPT=-d PERLDB_OPTS=NonStop perl 1.pl
   entering main::bar
    entering main::foo
```